# What is the relative processing speed of JSONObject.item vs JSONObject['item']?

Tags: javascript, json, jshint

I'm working on speeding up some old JavaScript code that uses a lot of the following structure:

```
var obj = {
            attr1: value,
            attr2: value2,
            ...
            attrN: valueN
          };

someFunction(obj['attr1']);
```

JSHint gives me the following advice:

```
['attr1'] is better written in dot notation.
```

So it prefers `obj.attr1` over `obj['attr1']`. I understand the aesthetic reason for this warning (explained [here](http://jslinterrors.com/a-is-better-written-in-dot-notation)), but which notation is faster? I would think that the former would be more efficient because the latter involves the conversion of a string literal, but I have nothing other than speculation to back that up.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: I really don't think dot/bracket optimization will speed up your code significantly.

Comment: Have you tried a benchmark at jsperf?

Comment: The docs note that "you can save three characters every time", which is telling. If you're accessing lots of properties this way, the size of the JS will be noticeably reduced. Smaller scripts, faster downloads.

Comment: Check out http://jsperf.com/

Comment: As kamituel mentioned, this is unlikely to improve performance. Look at other likely bottlenecks such as DOM manipulation, large data structures being looped over, or inefficient algorithms (Loops that are non-linear). jsperf is also a great suggestion.

Comment: Here is a banchmark [dot notation vs bracket notation](http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation/2)

Comment: They're going to be virtually identical - the only difference is that the parse is *slightly* more complicated with bracket notation because there's an extra production or two involved. Once the expressions are parsed I'd bet they're represented identically in the AST (or whatever the internal representation is). Note that in that jsperf they're running at about 1/35,000,000th of a second per operation, so this is not something worth worrying about at all.

Comment: Sheesh, thanks guys! I had not heard of jsperf.com, I'll be sure to use that in the future. @paulroub That's certainly one way to see the issue, but download speeds aren't my concern, processing speeds are.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach I realize there are probably other issues in the code, but I wanted to know if the JSHint error was for more than just aesthetics.

Comment: @pointy point taken, but beyond practical purposes this is also just something I'm curious about.

Comment: @EvanColeman sure, and that's fine, but understand that the two syntaxes end up with precisely the same semantics. The difference lies in where the property name comes from. Once the runtime has the object reference and the property name, nothing about the original code makes any difference. The source only has to be parsed once!

Comment: @EvanColeman There may have been early JS interpreters that didn't optimize this well. These days, it's probably just a stylistic thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're almost even. See these two jsperf examples:

http://jsperf.com/dot-operator-vs-array-notation
http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation/2

Both of them show them being within 1% similar, however, they both show that array notation is ever-so-slightly faster.

EDIT:

Browsing through newly created jsperfs, I found these two:

http://jsperf.com/mpaaa
http://jsperf.com/property-dot-versus-string

They both show almost the same, and, actually, after testing them multiple times, they showed different results (sometimes dot was faster, sometimes array notation)

It's a tie

ANOTHER EDIT:

The browserscope is wrong, although, at least for me, it shows some very uneven tests in other browsers, I tested it in one of the ones it showed a huge difference in, only to find similar results to what I already had found

Comment: BrowserScope seems to be a notable exception.

Comment: Heh, you found the benchmark I was creating before @hex494D49 posted his link.

Comment: Finally, 2,000 reputation!

Comment: @Markasoftware I'm feeling that. I just got past 2,000 recently myself